# Fitnesse eclipse project root path

Tags: eclipse, testing, automated-tests, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am using eclipse and I kept FitnesseRoot inside a project structure. Now, I want to have relative paths to my classfiles. 
Hows should I do it?

For eg:I have something like

```
!path h:/workspace/proj/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

!path h:/workspace/proj/WEB-INF/classes
```

I want something like

```
!path /proj/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

!path /proj/WEB-INF/classes
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have to add FitnesseRoot Folder on root path.

It solves the issue.

```
!path ..proj/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

!path ..proj/WEB-INF/classes
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using maven for your project? Then I would recommend the [maven-classpath plugin](https://github.com/amolenaar/fitnesse-maven-classpath).

Comment: No. Its simple JAVA web project. I am using ANT though